# Insert blank row after change in columnar data

Tags: function

Is there a way to add a blank row after each change in a column of data? I want to add a sum row for each change of name in col a. There are 5000 rows.

Comment: Neither your title, nor your text, nor indeed your tags, shed any light what tool, language pr technology you are asking about.

Comment: Apologies. I was referring to Excel. I have since found a means to do the job. Next problem is to sum each group of rows. Could I use grouping somehow?

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, feel free to delete this question and post a new one, or change this question so it makes sense. You should not ask several unrelated questions in one question. Correct tagging serves to attract experts in the given field who can answer your question the best. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you make the most effective questions. Finally, if you are asking about _using_ Excel, as opposed to _programming_ in Excel, this is not the right site: please consider using [su] instead.